# Select by Attributes - Strings with < 5 characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute, querystring

I have a column of zip codes which are strings.  Most of them are the usual 5 digit zip codes, but some are only 3 digits or missing a digit. (keep in mind, I need this column as strings for other reasons)

ex.

> **ZIP**
>   
> 234
>   
> 4566
>   
> 12345

I basically want to select everything that has less than 5 characters for further investigation.  I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm having a difficult time figuring it out.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! Will post it as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the **Select by Attributes** tool, you could enter the following [SQL query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/) to select all features with less than 5 characters in the `ZIP` field:

```
CHAR_LENGTH("ZIP") < 5
```

Answer (score -1):

you could also use

```
Left("ZIP", 5)
```

to select features with 5 digits.

Comment: This will return the first 5 characters of any attribute but has little relation to the length of the attribute.